# Calculate distance between two Latitudes and two Longitudes separately

Tags: math, geolocation, openstreetmap

I'm struggling to find out how to calculate the distances between two Latitudes and two Longitudes *separately*.

What I'm trying to do is the following:

I have n-Locations that define a contour of a real building of which I calculate the *mid-point* and now want to translate this contour into a virtual coordinate system based on the previous mentioned mid-point. The *mid-point* will be the origin of the virtual coordinate system and therefore I have to translate every contour Location relative to it. I was thinking of calculating the distance of each contour Location axis separately in relation to the mid-point and then use them as their new virtual positions.

Any hints of how I could calculate that?

Thanks in advance!

Jan S.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do what you want with less math of calculating the distance. Instead find the min and max for both the latitude and longitude of the building contour. This will be your bounding box.

To scale your X-axis: calculate distance between midpoint and min/max longitude at the same latitude as the mid-point. Scale the result accordingly (e.g., normalizing).

To scale your Y-axis: calculate distance between midpoint and min/max latitude at the same longitude as the mid-point. Scale the result accordingly (e.g., normalizing).

Comment: Thanks Andrew for your answer. Well I already got the BB part done. I think I understand where you going with your idea. I just have to use the lat or lon part of the BB min/max coordinate, use the counter part of the mid-point and then compute the distance between those two coordinates. But what do you mean by scaling / normalizing the contour locations? How would that look like?

Comment: You referred to a virtual coordinate system. You will want to convert the distance values to the units you are using such as meters, feet or some imaginary system.

Comment: Ya you're right. I was confused about the scaling part. I was thinking of calculating a scale factor and using it on every contour location but instead I just have to calculate the distance in meters between the mid-point and the contour point and will have the virtual system in meters.